# Copy-Item by header & timestamp

Tags: powershell, filter, header, timestamp

I am using the code below to filter out files depending on the headers in the file.

It works like a charm, but I have a problem with that it takes all the files in the `$InputDirectory`.
I would like to limit it so it only takes files that are 1-2 hours old.

There are two ways where I can get the date for this process.

Filename contains timestamp = XXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXX_valuereport_YYYYMMDDhhmmss.csv

The timestamp the file was created (please note we are talking about 800K-1M files in the directory and more is added every hour, so the fastest way would be appreciated.

So how do I insert something in my code, so it besides the header, only takes files that are <1-2 hours old?

Sorry about the code example, I am new to this site and not sure how to get it in the right order.

Nothing yet.

```
foreach ($FilePath in (Get-ChildItem $InputDirectory -File) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName) {
    $Header = Get-Content $FilePath -First 1

    # test for a string in the header line that distincts it from the other files
    if ($Header -match ';energy,Wh,') {
        # the substring ';energy,Wh,' defines this file as a 'HeatMeter' file
        Copy-Item -Path $FilePath -Destination $OutputPathHeat
    } elseif ($Header -match ';fabrication-no,,inst-value,0,0,0;datetime,,inst-value,0,0,0;volume,m3') {
        # the substring ';datetime,,inst-value,0,0,0;volume,m3' defines this file as a 'WaterMeter' file
       Copy-Item -Path $FilePath -Destination $OutputPathWater
    } else {
        # if all key substrings above did not match, move to the 'Other' directory
        Copy-Item -Path $FilePath -Destination $OutputPathOther
    }
```

Comment: Is the timestamp in the filename/header different to the actual filesystem timestamp on the file?  If not, then you can easily filter on that property for files less than two hours old.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to filter a directory listing. The easiest way is to pipe the result of `Get-ChildItem` through `Where-Object` like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $InputDirectory -File | 
Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddHours(-2) } | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | 
ForEach-Object {
    $FilePath = $_
    $Header = Get-Content $FilePath -First 1

    # test for a string in the header line that distincts it from the other files
    if ($Header -match ';energy,Wh,') {
        # the substring ';energy,Wh,' defines this file as a 'HeatMeter' file
        Copy-Item -Path $FilePath -Destination $OutputPathHeat
    }
    elseif ($Header -match ';fabrication-no,,inst-value,0,0,0;datetime,,inst-value,0,0,0;volume,m3') {
        # the substring ';datetime,,inst-value,0,0,0;volume,m3' defines this file as a 'WaterMeter' file
        Copy-Item -Path $FilePath -Destination $OutputPathWater
    }
    else {
        # if all key substrings above did not match, move to the 'Other' directory
        Copy-Item -Path $FilePath -Destination $OutputPathOther
    }
}
```

It checks that the CreationTime is greater than now - 2h. Note that the last modified (`LastWriteTime`) timestamp may also be suitable for your use case.